# How can you reopen the plots pane in spyder?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spyder, python-3.8

On installing Spyder, I deleted the help and plots pane in the top right hand corner of Spyder, leaving only the console on the right. Does anyone know how to reopen these panes after removing them?

thanks

[My current console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le2jA.png)

Answer (score 2):

In the top bar open `View > Panes` and check `Plots`.

Also, shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+G` should also open the Plots window.

Comment: The same menu was able to enable/ disable other panes, but for plots it was already checked, and checking / unchecking it did not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to solve this (Jakub Holan has the best answer to try first, but it didn't work for me). Even a soft setting reset from inside spyder didn't work. The solution was to close Spyder, search for "reset spyder settings" in windows navigation search, and open the "reset spyder settings" file.